# Option map() returns a reference to data owned by the current function

Tags: rust

I want to do something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    pub name: String,
}

fn is_empty(s: &str) -> bool {
    s.len() == 0
}

fn main() {
    let entity = Some(Foo { name: "some-name".to_string() });
    
    let name: &str = entity
        .map(|it| it.name.as_ref())
        .unwrap_or( "onother-name");

    println!("is it empty: {}", is_empty(name));
}
```

but it compiles with error: "returns a reference to data owned by the current function". How can I fix it elegantly? Make a copy of string and use String instead &str seems to me non optimal. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`Option::map` consumes the `Option`. You should call `.as_ref()` on the `Option` first to get `Option<&T>` and then call `.map` on it:

```rust
struct Foo {
    name: String,
}

fn is_empty(s: &str) -> bool {
    s.len() == 0
}

fn main() {
    let entity = Some(Foo {
        name: "some-name".to_string(),
    });

    let name: &str = entity
        .as_ref()
        .map(|it| it.name.as_ref())
        .unwrap_or("onother-name");

    println!("is it empty: {}", is_empty(name));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64162973e2c0a67eb01db642203d1d4c)